# How do I execute the SHOW PARTITIONS command on an Athena table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I'm using AWS Athena with AWS Glue for the first time, with S3 providing a 'folder' structure which maps to the partitions in my data - I'm getting into the concepts so please excuse any mistaken description!

I'm looking at what happens when I add data to my S3 bucket and see that new folders are ignored. Digging deeper I came across the 'SHOW PARTITIONS' command, as described here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/show-partitions.html, and I'm trying to execute this against my test tables using the Athena query editor, with a mind that I'll go onto use the 'ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITION' command to add the new S3 folders.

I'm trying to execute the 'SHOW PARTITIONS' command in the AWS Athena Console Query Editor:

```
SHOW PARTITIONS "froms3_customer-files"."unit"
```

but when I try to execute it I see this message:

```
line 1:17: missing {'from', 'in'} at '"froms3_customer-files"' (service: amazonathena; status code: 400; error code: invalidrequestexception; request id: c0c0c351-2d42-4da4-b1f3-223b1733db65)
```

I'm struggling to understand what this is telling me, can anyone help me here?

Comment: remove the double quotes from database and table name.

Comment: @HarshBafna same result I'm afraid

Comment: the syntax : show partitions db.table works for me. I get the same error as yours when I add double quotes in db name and table name.

Comment: @HarshBafna You think it might be the _ and - in my name? Can I escape them somehow?

Comment: that could be one of the cases. AFAIK - is not supported athena identifiers.

Comment: Athena table, view, database, and column names cannot contain special characters, other than underscore (_). How did you manage to create the database name with a hyphen (-).?

Comment: @HarshBafna I recreated my database without the _ and - and indeed the command works. Thanks for the pointers, if you add an answer below I'll gladly accept it after your comments got me the answer :-)

Comment: @HarshBafna It appears AWS Glue allows you to create databases using characters not supported by AWS Athena - not good!

Comment: Interesting.. I was wondering how you managed to create that database in the first place. I will definitely try it out from glue. :-)

Comment: @Eliveny, It is because constraint is on Athena as it uses Presto engine. On other hand, if you use redshift spectrum/EMR, you can able to access partitions even with hyphen (-) character in table. It is matter of which client tool you use to access partitions ( Glue Data Catalogue)  :P  Glue Data Catalogue is independent of client used to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Athena does not supports hyphen in database name.

> Athena table, view, database, and column names cannot contain special
>   characters, other than underscore (_).

Also remove the double quotes from the show partitions command.

```
SHOW PARTITIONS froms3_customer_files.unit
```

References :

[Athena table and database naming convention](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/tables-databases-columns-names.html)

[Athena show partitions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/show-partitions.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see all the partitions that are created till now you can use following command

```
SHOW PARTITIONS DB_NAME.TABLE_NAME
```

If you want to view the keys along which table is partitioned you can view it through UI in following way:

**1. Click on the table menu options.**

[image]

**2. Click on Show Properties**

[image]

**3. Click on partitions to see partition.**